# How to make text responsive in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I want to make a text responsive and it should accordingly change its size depending on the device width.

Code:

```css
.aligned { 
display: flex; 
align-items: top; 
}

.p{
padding: 15px; 
}

img{
border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
width: 800px;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.35em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<section>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/img/profile.jpg">  
  <img src="assets/img/profile.jpg" align="left" width="370" height="500">

<!-- <div style="display:inline-block;"> to put text under something or start new --> 
  <div class="aligned">
    <div class="p">
           <p>I am currently exploring different options that will allow me to combine my interests in Business and Technology, and pursue a combined-degree in those fields. Motivated by my love for numbers, I started to explore the many ways I can use my Mathematical knowledge and implement it into different areas. While I always had a passion for business, I was introduced to Computer Science in my junior years of high school, and I came to know that I was genuinely passionated about learning it. It offers a holistic approach to solve problems which I admire, and since then, I have transformed my interest into a personal hobby!</p>
           <p>I would always like to challenge myself and learn new programming langauges to increase the size of my toolbox. I was inspired by one of my friends to take my programming skills and put it into a good use; thus, I was introduced to competitive programming and large coding events such as hackathons!</p>
           <p>The intellectual challenges, creativity, and logic programming offers has always further strengthened the inevitable bond between us. All you need is a notepad, and the world becomes your <i>canvas.</i></p>
           <p>Challenging myself allows me to not only grow outside my comfort zone, but gives a new perspective towards life, and how there are no limitations/boundaries that halt you from growing! It is everlasting. Once you develop the growth mindset, your journey just never comes to a complete stop! You are able to focus on self-development and different ways to come out of the comfort zone.</p>
          <blockquote>
          Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
          <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
           </blockquote>
           
        </div>
    </section><!-- End About Section -->
```

So I want to make the text and the blockquote (that appears at the bottom) responsive, and it should change size depending on the width of the device.

On a mobile device, I would like everything to be aligned vertically right after the image but on a larger device, it should look like what it is in the output of the code I sent.

This is what I was suggested by a user but it did not seem to work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
    font-size: 10vh; // Or the unit you want
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Basically, I want the text to be vertically displayed under the picture on a mobile device but on a large device, it should be displayed what I sent in the code above.

### Update

This is what my output looks like:
[image]

I do not want the image to be small, I do not know why it is small after the changes applied, and the text should be right under it.

Comment: Your media query does not contain a selector. What elements are you trying to change with it?

Comment: the font size if applicable, and then I want to make the text vertically positioned after the image only on mobile device or smaller screens.

Comment: if you want response `font-size` then use `rem` units for your text in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove align="left" from the img tag in HTML.
Then add float: left; to the img ruleset in CSS.
Finally, modifying your media query to include the section and img selectors:

```css
.aligned { 
display: flex; 
align-items: top; 
}

.p{
padding: 15px; 
}

img{
  border: 5px solid #555;
  float:left;
}

blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
width: 800px;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.35em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  img{
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  section{
    font-size: 10vh; // Or the unit you want
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/img/profile.jpg">  
  <img src="assets/img/profile.jpg" width="370" height="500">

<!-- <div style="display:inline-block;"> to put text under something or start new --> 
  <div class="aligned">
    <div class="p">
           <p>I am currently exploring different options that will allow me to combine my interests in Business and Technology, and pursue a combined-degree in those fields. Motivated by my love for numbers, I started to explore the many ways I can use my Mathematical knowledge and implement it into different areas. While I always had a passion for business, I was introduced to Computer Science in my junior years of high school, and I came to know that I was genuinely passionated about learning it. It offers a holistic approach to solve problems which I admire, and since then, I have transformed my interest into a personal hobby!</p>
           <p>I would always like to challenge myself and learn new programming langauges to increase the size of my toolbox. I was inspired by one of my friends to take my programming skills and put it into a good use; thus, I was introduced to competitive programming and large coding events such as hackathons!</p>
           <p>The intellectual challenges, creativity, and logic programming offers has always further strengthened the inevitable bond between us. All you need is a notepad, and the world becomes your <i>canvas.</i></p>
           <p>Challenging myself allows me to not only grow outside my comfort zone, but gives a new perspective towards life, and how there are no limitations/boundaries that halt you from growing! It is everlasting. Once you develop the growth mindset, your journey just never comes to a complete stop! You are able to focus on self-development and different ways to come out of the comfort zone.</p>
          <blockquote>
          Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
          <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
           </blockquote>
           
        </div>
    </section><!-- End About Section -->
```

Comment: also do I have to reference the selector in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my answer to provide more information. This is working on my end.

Comment: Sorry one more thing, the blockquote does not change size depending on screen, it is really small on mobile device

Comment: Vh is viewport height. Try using a different unit. For example 1.5rem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your `display: flex` at your section because it will serve as the container for your image and text.

so change this

```
.aligned { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: top; 
}
```

to this

```
section { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: top; 
}
```

or you can just transfer the `.align` class to section

Next, your media query is in wrong syntax and the max screen is too small. Even the smallest screen (Iphone5s) is 375px. In my opinion, 500px is a safe max-width for mobile devices (just my preference). Here's the correct code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  section {
    font-size: 10vh; // Or the unit you want
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

I forgot to mention: For `display: flex` to work, you need to place your elements inside a div so flex can align it the way you want. So what you do is place your image into a div like this

```
<div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/img/profile.jpg">  
  <img src="assets/img/profile.jpg" align="left" width="370" height="500">
</div>
```

In short, your html structure should look like this

```
<section>
  <div>
     place your image here
  </div>
  <div>
     place all your texts here
  </div>
</section>
```